# Logcat only showing warnings, not showing errors

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

I am developing an Android app in Eclipse and have been using a Google Pixel C for a year now. For the past year, I've successfully connected the device and used Logcat to debug, and it would give me any errors/warnings when things went wrong.

I stopped developing for about 3 months and came back to it, and suddenly, logcat doesn't seem to be working. In particular, logcat is clearly detecting my device; anytime I disconnect it, it says "Device disconnected." But all it is outputting is a bunch of seemingly unrelated warnings. When I run my app and it crashes, I get no error messages.

I have no filters set up, and in DDMS it appears that the focus is on the device. I have restarted Eclipse, restarted the tablet, killed/restarted/reset adb, and nothing seems to be fixing the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would recommend migrating your project to Android Studio.

In filters you need to select "Show only selected application."  You need to have a filter or else it will show everything.  I would also make sure in logcat you make sure to select your device, select the process you are debugging, and change the logging mode to verbose.